# Basic authentication in asp.net avoided if runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="True"

Tags: asp.net, caching, httpmodule, basic-authentication

We have one module which does internal redirection to real aspx pages. He is also in charge for directly serving cached/compressed HTML/txt/cs/js output to client.

Here is how web.config looks like for modules section:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="True">      
  <remove name="RequestInterceptor" />
  <add type="Lib.Request.RequestInterceptor" name="RequestInterceptor" />
  <remove name="Session" />
  <add type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" name="Session" />
</modules>
```

Basic authentication is turned on on IIS7. When first visitor comes to site login popup shows and he is correctly authenticated, and then pages which he visits get cached.
When next visitor comes authentication pop up doesn't show up, unless he visits a page which was not visited by previous visitor (page that is not cached). Once the cache has expired, authentication works again until the page content gets cached, and so on.

Is there a way to force authentication for every visitor? Maybe we need to add basic authentication module to module section of web.config (how to do that)?

Thanks in advance.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because httpmodule intercepts each request, server is not able to map appropriate handler for static files, dynamic files, and among others secuirty authentication.

Answer (score 2):

While searching for an answer to a related question I came across this post:

[Don't use runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" when getting your MVC routing to work](http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/06/dont-use-modules-runallmanagedmodulesfo.html)

> It seems to be common advice to make your modules section of your
>   web.config say . In
>   fact this is quite a drastic thing to do to solve the routing problem
>   and has global effects that could CAUSE ERRORS. ... This highly
>   recommended fix can cause other problems. These problems come in the
>   form of making all your registered HTTP modules run on every request,
>   not just managed requests (e.g. .aspx). This means modules will run on
>   ever .jpg .gif .css .html .pdf etc.

And, while I'm not using MVC in my WCF REST Service, it did fix my (other) problem and this advice against inappropriate or overuse of `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` may be warranted.

Comment: (There's no need to vote this answer up since I didn't create the answer myself.  It merely adds some support/context to the OP's self-provided accepted answer.)